# Autoplay video in ReactJS don`t work with Chrome

Tags: javascript, reactjs, video, autoplay

I just created website with ReactJS and notised that video in main page doesnt starts playing in Chrome. It only starts playing when I go to different page and then go back to the main page. Does someone have any suggestions please? Somewhere I saw that they fixed it with JQuery, but I dont wanna add JQuery into the React until its really necessary.

I used video like this

```
<video src={Video} muted playsInline={true} autoPlay={true} loop disablePictureInPicture></video>
```

And also like this

```
<video playsInline loop disablePictureInPicture autoPlay muted>
    <source src={Video} type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

Also the "muted" doesn't appear in dom..
In action it can be seen here: https://www.chiptuning-brno.cz/
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So finally solution is to pass "muted" via ref like this:

```
const videoRef = useRef(null)

  useEffect(() => {
    const { current: videoElement } = videoRef
    videoElement.setAttribute('muted', '')
  }, [])

<video src={Video} ref={videoRef} playsInline autoPlay loop disablePictureInPicture muted />
```

As I saw, it is known issue for few years and this solution is from here:

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/10389#issuecomment-605689475